# Programatically creating UINavigationController which isn't a rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am aware that it is possible for you to do:

```
let foo = MyView()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: foo)

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = nav

window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Or something like that in AppDelegate.swift and have a navigation controller up and running. However, what if my intended navigation controller *isn't* my rootViewController? Do I do something like this or is there a completely different approach?

Comment: You create your navigation controller instance as `UINavigationController(rootViewController: your_view_controller)` or using one of the other three `init` of  `UINavigationController ` thats all, all other statements in your code is simply setting navigation controller as windows root view controller :) If you don't wanna do that don't write it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since a `UINavigationController` is merely a subclassed `UIViewController`, I believe the *only* other code-only approach is to make it a child view controller to your *actual* root controller:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

addChild(navController)
view.addSubview(navController.view)
navController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

That code is for your "root" `UIViewController that will contain`navController`.

My usage is subtly different. I actually have *two custom/subclassed nav controllers *inside* a view controller, and I use auto layout to place them where I need them. Your needs were pretty vague on details, but if you do not want your nav controller to be a root, I see no reason why you couldn't make one a child of the root and have it be full screen. (You should even be able to `present` it.

If my code isn't enough to help you, let me know and I'll expand on things.

If you wish to use a storyboard, there is another option: Create a new storyboard, make everything in it embedded in a nav controller, and open it.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "mySecondStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboardCompose.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myRootVC") as! MyNextViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myRootVC)
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

But please note, you are *both* presenting a view controller *and* making it a root!

Just remember, a `UINavigationController` is merely a subclassed "container" `UIViewController` with some enhancements for navigation like push/pop.